# How to wait for download finish?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, listener

I download the file with usage of the 1st code [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Downloading_Files).
How can I wait (i.e. run request as synchronous) or know when download is finished?

Upd. Ok, looks like I should do something like:

```
myfunction = function(url) {
// downloading file here

  persist.progressListener = {
    onStateChange: function(aWebProgress, aRequest, aStateFlags, aStatus) {
      if (aStatus == STATE_STOP) {

      }
    }
  }
// once download is finished, myfunction should return result
}
```

How `myfunction` can return result, if I use listener?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Threads#Waiting_for_a_background_task_to_complete) is the solution.

Comment: No, [`nsIDownloadManager.addListener`)(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIDownloadManager#addListener%28%29) should be the solution.

Comment: @Wladimir, seems you've missed first link in my question - I don't use Download Manager.

Comment: You don't but I think that `nsIWebBrowserPersist` does - it is primarily meant for saving web pages and that goes through the download manager.